# Get data out of Parse.com and display on android

Tags: java, android, database, parse-platform

Please could you give me some ideas and maybe parts of code, I am trying to get data out of a Parse.com table and display it on my android phone in either a TextView or a TableView.

I can manage to get one value out however, there are three in the table that should be shown.

I just can't seem to work out where I am going wrong! Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
 private void forLoadingView(String c_id) throws ParseException
             {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Review");
            query.whereEqualTo("c_id", c_id);
        query.orderByDescending("rating");
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> reviewList, ParseException e) {
                    if (e==null && reviewList!= null)
                    {

                        for(ParseObject object : reviewList) {
     String score = object.getString("rating");
                        String review = object.getString("review");
                        String name = object.getString("name");
reviews.setText(review + " " + name + " " + score);

                }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }


                }
            });
```

EDIT:

Now my code looks a little more like this:

```
final List<String> infoList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query =
            new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Review");
   query.whereEqualTo("c_id", c_id);
        query.orderByDescending("rating");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
            //fill your list or adapter by using objects
            for(ParseObject obj : objects) {
                infoList.add(object.getString("score"));
                    infoList.add(object.getString("review"));
                    infoList.add(object.getString("name"));
               }
            }
        }
    });


reviews.setText(infoList.toString());
```

But it still does not print out... instead there is a null pointer exception as (I guess) the information isn't being sent to the infoList. Have you got any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What does this mean?  query.whereEqualTo("c_id", c_id);   Aren't you querying for a specific id here? Do all three objects share the same c_id ?

Comment: Yes, all objects share the same C_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it worked for me, let me know if worked for you as well:

```
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query =
            new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(yourQuery);
    query.whereEqualTo(querykey, queryvalue);
    query.addAscendingOrder(orderKey);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
            //fill your list or adapter by using objects
            for(ParseObject obj : objects) {
               result.add(obj.getString(someKey));
               }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! So I changed my code to yours and then
  `if (e == null) {
                for(ParseObject object : messages) {
               //fill your adapter by using messages
                String score = object.getString("rating");
                      String review = object.getString("review");
                      String name = object.getString("name");
                reviews.setText(review + " " + name + " " + score); etc`
This still only printed one thing but when I sysout'd the review it showed all values in terminal, do you know to get this to show on screen?

Comment: If I mistake not ,You are happy with the result of your query but have problems with extracting data from the ParseObject?

Comment: yes, I am happy with the query. Inside the variable review are the three items that it is meant to hold. However, when I ask it to set the textView it only displays the last item. Do you know how to get it to display all three?

Comment: I recommend you to get a log from the returned object (or the string you created from) to make sure that is different from the output result of the textview, then make sure that your textview initialized properly.

Comment: So the log does show the correct results. The only problem with the TextView is that in order for it to access the variables rating, review and name it needs to be in the query box. How else would I initialise it?

Comment: I meant this by initialization : TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(id);

Comment: where do you use setText() method ? if you're using in the done method like your code block above, it will only show the last ParseObject data, did you consider this !?

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case... where should I do it instead? how to do you then access the variables in the done statement?

Comment: That's simple , just create a string array or a list of strings in your activity scope, then assign the returned values by done() method to the array using a loop.got it !?

Comment: that seems to make sense! I just don't know how to do it? Would you be able to help me code it? Thank you so much for all your help

Comment: I edited my answer in order to save results to an array for the case you want just access the result, If you need to show the result in a ListView you can use an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Comment: So I have followed what you have said and then called  `reviews.setText(result.toString());` but this has called a null pointer exception as nothing is being written to reviews... do you know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Review");` with `ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Review");`

According to Parse Documentation (refer [here](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#getQuery(java.lang.String))), ParseQuery.getQuery(class_name) method retrieves all objects in the class.

> public static  ParseQuery getQuery(String
>   className) Creates a new query for the given class name. A default
>   query with no further parameters will retrieve all ParseObjects of the
>   provided class name. Parameters: className - The name of the class to
>   retrieve ParseObjects for. Returns: A new ParseQuery.

Whereas `ParseQuery` object can be queried if one instantiates it by calling `ParseQuery()` constructor.

Comment: sadly that does not do anything. The query is getting the correct values, they are just not showing correctly in the TextView

Comment: Make sure that TextView reviews is global to forLoadingView method

and

try setting text like this
reviews.setText(object.getString("review") + " " +object.getString("name") + " " +  object.getString("rating"));

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
StringBuilder str_infoList = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : infoList)
    {
        str_infoList.append(s);
        str_infoList.append(" ");
    }

reviews.setText(str_infoList);
```